# svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted

Tags: ssl, svn, ssl-certificate, svnx

I am using the svnX Version 2.0 (2.0.017068) and I can't connect. We already have a certificate for it, but it is giving me these errors:

svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.sample.com/svn/web'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted

Comment: I guess you'll need to 1) work out whether the certificate really is valid, e.g. try it with a browser or `openssl s_client` or `curl` or similar; 2) if it is, check the list of CAs that your SVN client is configured with to see why it isn't treating the certificate as valid.

Comment: 1) the certificate is valid, the certificateis from a local CA. 2) Where do I configure the list on the svnx software. I looked at all of the options (File, edit, Working Copy,   Repository .... etc)

Comment: And all of your other software thinks it is valid, and will show you a full certification path back to the root CA? I don't know SVNX but I'd guess either it uses the Mac keychain or a bundle of CAs installed in its own folders, and I'd guess this won't be configurable through the UI except maybe on an 'advanced' menu somewhere.

Comment: @Rup Thank you for your help. I wanted to share this, .https://dikant.de/2007/08/27/importing-ssl-certificates-into-svnx/. By running this command `svn list https://whatever.server.com/repository/` i was able to fix it. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

It suddenly happened to me today. I followed the steps from Rick: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Collaborator/Server-SSL-Certificate-verification-failed-issues-is-not-trusted/td-p/96838

> Please try running an "svn ls" or something similar from inside your working/checkout directory. You should be prompted to accept the certificate, make sure that you accept it permanently.

I did an `svn update` on the working directory.

Automatically, it asked me to accept the certificate.
Just accept it.

Comment: `Just accept it.` - there must be a better way. why does this fail with `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`? i get this error for the domain `github.com`, so the validation should work